# Functional components, reactJS. I have a button next to a span inside a div. I want the button to target the span so I can delete the span on click

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-functional-component

Basically, I am asking for what I put in the title. I have a span and button next to each other, and onclick I want the button to be able to either hide the span or completely remove it from state.
[This is what the page looks like with the button next to the span (UPDATED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Dye.png)
Here is my code

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";

const SavedStrain = (props) => {
  console.log(props.savedList);

  const editResponse = () => {

  }

  const removeResponse = () => {
    const removeFromSavedList = props.removeFromSavedList;
    //removeFromSavedList()
  }

  console.log(props)


  return (
    <div className="saved-list">
      <h3> Saved Strains: </h3>

      {props.savedList.map(strain => (
        <div>
          <NavLink to={`/strains/${strain}`}>
            <span className='name'> {strain} </span>
          </NavLink>
          <Button className='delete' onClick={removeResponse}>Delete</Button>
        </div>
      ))}
      
    </div>
  )
}
 
export default SavedStrain;
```

[Here is my props (UPDATED)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX9pQ.png)

Here is my component where removeFromSavedList is located.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import UserCreation from './components/UserCreation';
import Login from "./components/Login";
import StrainCard from './components/StrainCard';
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import NavBarComponent from "./components/NavBarComponent";
import SavedStrain from './components/SavedStrain';
import Strain from './components/Strain';
import StrainDetails from './components/StrainDetails';

function App(props) {
  const [strains, setStrains] = useState([]);
  const [strain, setStrain] = useState([]);
  const [savedList, setSavedList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getStrains = () => {
      axios
        .get('http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/CEIl7eN/strains/search/all')
        .then(response => {
          setStrains(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Server Error', error.response);
        });
    }
    getStrains();
  }, []);


console.log(strains)

  useEffect(() => {
    setStrain(Object.keys(strains).slice(0, 20))
  }, [strains])

  const addToSavedList = strain => {
    setSavedList([...savedList, strain]);
    console.log(savedList);
  };

  const removeFromSavedList = (strain) => {
    setSavedList(savedList.filter(element => element !== strain))
  }

  const editSavedStrain = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSavedList(strain === event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <Container className="App">
        <NavBarComponent />
      <Route exact path='/'>
        <Link to='/login'>Log in</Link>
      </Route>
        <Route exact path='/login'>
            <Login />
        </Route>
      <Route exact path='/signup'>
        <UserCreation />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path='/strains' render= { () => <StrainCard strains={strains} />} />
      <Route exact path='/strains/:strain' render = {(props) => <StrainDetails {...props} strains={strains} addToSavedList={addToSavedList} savedList={savedList} />} />
      <Route exact path='/savedstrains' render = {(props) => <SavedStrain {...props} savedList={savedList} removeFromSavedList={removeFromSavedList} editSavedStrain={editSavedStrain} /> } />
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I noticed that `removeFromSavedList()` is commented, it seems like that's what you need. Was there an issue with it?

Comment: Yes, I tried putting strain in the argument for removeFromSavedList, but strain is undefined. check out the props image i uploaded

Comment: I basically just need a way to call each individual span so I can implement that in the removeResponse function. the classname 'name' wont work because it will just remove all of the spans (i think)

Comment: Your screenshot already shows savedList as empty. So, basically you won't be getting any list. What is that you want exactly to happen?

Comment: Sorry, that was incorrect. I updated the images. I want to be able to delete the span on click of the delete button (and hopefully remove that button with the span as well)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `removeFromSavedList` handler with the strain you get from your map.

```
<Button className='delete' onClick={() => props.removeFromSavedList(strain)}>Delete</Button>
```

Note that this replaces `removeResponse` from `SavedStrain`, which you can remove.

Comment: That made an infinite loop, that is why removeResponse is there (i dont call it when i set it to onClick). I think that the removeFromSavedList might need to be edited, because when I set element === strain, it removes all of the spans and buttons.

Comment: Can you show exactly what code you're using that's looping?